# Issues getting Ruby-on-Rails 6/Webpack + Bootstrap working properly together

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm back on the code for the first time in 10 years and generally enjoying the process EXCEPT the part where I'm trying to get Bootstrap to work with Rails6.

I've worked my way through half a dozen tutorials but each seems to have a slightly different approach, and although I'm slightly less confused about the whole process now than when I started I still can't get my Rails 6 application to correctly render some Bootstrap styles (e.g.: Cards and Dropdown menus do not render as expected -- but changing my Bootstrap/Webpack config has them showing correctly, but something else will break.)

I'm totally frustrated with the whole complicated process and would appreciate some guidance.

My configs:

```
ruby -v      
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x86_64-darwin20]
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
ruby '~> 2.6.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.5.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'

gem 'devise'
gem 'toastr-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 2.0'
gem 'cancancan'
```

(etc.)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "dcm",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrapper": "^0.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append(
    'Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

application.scss

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'toastr';
```

application.js

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

import "bootstrap"
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import "../stylesheets/application"
global.toastr = require("toastr")

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

application.scss (currently commented out)

```
// @import 'toastr';
// @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>XXXXX</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Appreciate any insights you can offer as to why this is causing me problems!

Comment: https://mentalized.net/journal/2019/10/19/use-sass-modules-in-rails/ - the same setup applies with the older @import directive.

Comment: Thanks Max - nothing I've seen previously suggests I need a different sass system and I don't have compilation issues.

Comment: Both the sass-rails (the Ruby compiler) and sassc-rails (libsass) gem are depreciated. The Ruby compiler has been eol for a long time and is hella slow. Libsass was depreciated more recently leaving only Dart-sass. Dart-sass is the only compiler that includes the new `@use` directive that replaces `@include` which will eventually break your app when you upgrade the front-end packages.

Comment: Thanks max - now I have a headache...

Comment: If you want a quick and temporary solution swap sass-rails for sassc-rails and you'll see a huge speed increase in assets compilation.

Comment: Good tip - thanks. I see also a standard deployment of dart-sass is in the works.

Answer (score 0):

Folks I think I've figured this out. I followed this tutorial which was very helpful and provided a good explanation of how things work (and gave me confidence my config would work consistently in development and production):

https://www.vic-l.com/setup-bootstrap-in-rails-6-with-webpacker-for-development-and-production

But I also just looked at the CSS file that was generated & delivered (via dev tools in chrome) and compared it with the bootstrap classes I'd defined in my code, which was based on the various tutorials I'd read, and found there was some mismatch. So I also re-worked my CSS based on directly reading the Bootstrap docs for my version of Bootstrap and managed to resolve the bulk of my issues.

Thanks for reading :-)